# How to speed up OGRE for displaying multiple copies of same mesh and skeleton?

Tags: performance, graphics, rendering, mesh, ogre

I am a OGRE newbie, trying to use it in research. I am rendering 50 copies of an animal character. The characeter has a skeleton of 20 bones. The body mesh on the skeleton has 35K vertices and 70K faces.

In the scene, I have 50 characters, all built from this same skeleton and mesh. However, after each frame, I need to change the joint angles of each of the 50 characters by different amounts. So, each of the characters takes a pose that is different from each other. And the poses all change after every frame.

I am getting a frame rate of 35FPS for this setup. What are the tricks I can use to speedup the framerate or rendering?